# Pass parameter value by apending/updating string in Multiselect parameter

Tags: javascript, pentaho

I am new to Pentaho BI tool (pentaho-cde). I want to update selected values and assign to parameter.

I have created Multiselect component and simple parameter.

I have added javascript code in post change methode of Multiselect component as ,

```
function(s){
alert(s); // selected values = "08-01-2013,08-02-2013"
var appendval = s+",08-05-2013"; //after append "08-01-2013,08-02-2013,08-05-2013"
var  arrayappend =  appendval.toString().split(","); 
arrayappend = "'" + arrayappend.join("','") + "'";
if (typeof arrayappend == 'string') arrayappend = [arrayappend];
alert(arrayappend);  // alert as = '07-29-2013','08-01-2013','08-05-2013'
//Dashboards.fireChange('solddate',['07-29-2013','08-01-2013','08-05-2013']);//this works 
Dashboards.fireChange('solddate',arrayappend); // but this is not working
}
```

As I mention there in firechange event if i passed value directly it will works but if i passed value through array then it will not works, I dont know what i am missing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Actually i am converting it to "quoted And CommaSeparated" and then cast to array so that Dashboard.fireChange is not working initially. I have update the code and skip the intermidiate steps as

```
function(s){
var appendval = s+",08-05-2013";
var  arrayappend =  appendval.toString().split(","); 
Dashboards.fireChange('solddate',arrayappend); 
}
```

Thanks